# Is $M/gNg^{-1}$ abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm working on an exercise in Dummit & Foote:

> Let $G$ be a finite group. Prove that the following are equivalent:
>
> (i) $G$ is solvable
>
> (ii) $G$ has a chain of subgroups: $1=H_0\trianglelefteq H_1 \trianglelefteq H_2\trianglelefteq\dots\trianglelefteq H_s = G$ such that $H_{i+1}/H_i$ is cyclic, $0\le i \le s-1$.
>
> (iii) all composition factors of $G$ are of prime order
>
> (iv) $G$ has a chain of subgroups: $1=N_0\trianglelefteq N_1 \trianglelefteq N_2 \trianglelefteq \dots \trianglelefteq N_t = G$ such that each $N_i$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $N_{i+1}/N$ is abelian, $0\le i\le t-1$
>
> [For (iv), prove that a minimal nontrivial normal subgroup $M$ of $G$ is necessarily abelian, and then use induction. To see that $M$ is abelian, let $N\trianglelefteq M$ be of prime index (by (iii)) and show that $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy\in N$ for all $x,y\in M$. Apply the same argument to $gNg^{-1}$ to show that $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ lies in the intersection of all G-conjugates of $N$ and use the minimality of $M$ to conclude that $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy=1$.]

I have trouble understanding the hint giving at the bottom. I know that $M/N$ must be abelian because it has prime order, meaning that it must be cyclic. The fact that $M/N$ is abelian implies $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy\in N$ for all $x,y\in M$. However, I don't see why we can "apply the same argument to $gNg^{-1}$". $M/gNg^{-1}$ is not necessarily abelian for an arbitrary $g$.

Comment: $gNg^{-1}$ has the same index as $N.$

Answer (score 1):

Anne Bauval's comment gives the answer that corresponds to the hint in (iv): $gNg^{-1}$ has the same order as $N$ and hence the same (prime) index in $M$, since $M$ is finite.

Here is an alternative: if $\phi$ is an automorphism of any group $M$ and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $M$, then $\phi(N)$ is a normal subgroup of $M$ and $M/N$ is isomorphic to $M/\phi(N)$.  This applies here since $\phi(m)=gmg^{-1}$ defines an automorphism of $M$.

The claim is easy to prove; here's a sketch.  Define $\psi:M\to M/N$ by $\psi(m)=\phi^{-1}(m)N$.  It's clear that $\psi$ is a surjective homorphism with kernel $\phi(N)$, so the first isomorphism theorem implies $M/\phi(N)$ is isomorphic to $M/N$.